# Error message on combining ranges using Union Function

Tags: excel, vba, range, union

I am fairly new to VBA coding so please excuse my elementary understanding and vernacular.  I am trying to create a sub to combine an existing named range, "invoice_totals" with a new cell on the active sheet the protocol is run.  The named range exists in a scope of the entire workbook.  I did not define the scope for this to a specific sheet, due to the fact this range references multiple cells across multiple sheets. See picture for named range definition. Everytime I run it I recieve a "Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed.  Debugging highlights the "set oldrange" line of code, which is the first reference to the named range "invoice_totals".  Anyone have an idea why I am getting this error.  Thanks in advance for the help.

[Named Range"Invoice_Totals" Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66vSR.png)

```
Sub addsheettorange()
    
    Dim newrange As Range
    Dim oldrange As Range
    Set oldrange = Range("invoice_totals")
    Set newrange = Union(oldrange, Range("E1"))
    Range("invoice_totals").RefersTo = newrange
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Ranges cannot be split across multiple worksheets, but must refer to only a single worksheet

Comment: I can use this named range in a normal =sum(invoice_totals) and it returns the proper value.  Basically the refers to: =sheet1:sheet7$E$7! reference all E7 cells on the sheets in the range.